Unable to render a circle over my touch in AR application
I'm trying to render a circle over my touch in my AR application, as shown in this image.
enter image description here
I am following Unity learn AR pathway, The following were steps to do so.
Steps to insert a circle
This is my Script Graph, please guide me what have i done wrong?
enter image description here
